# FTP in Flash/Flex - sandbox error

Tags: apache-flex, flash, ftp

I'm trying to embed an FTP client in to a web page using Flash. I'm using [FlexFTP](http://maliboo.pl/projects/FlexFTP/), which appears to be designed for AIR. I've modified it to use a FileReference so it can run in the Flash plugin. I only need to connect to one server, and I have an appropriate socket policy server running on that server.

I can connect and log in just fine, but when I try to upload a file, I get a security sandbock violation (error 2048) saying "cannot load data from 127.0.0.1:38422" thrown from ceatePassiveSocket().

I'm beginning to think that it is not possible to do FTP from Flash because of the need to open a port locally. Is there a way around it, or can I get authoritative confirmation that it is not possible?

Comment: My intution is that this isn't possible.  I thought even FlexFTP was very limited.  But, perhaps I'll be surprised by the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in flash (browser), but you need to create an socket policy/crossdomain.xml, which allows flash to connect on the port , even if its local( testing it inside the browser).The file spec is located here http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html

Comment: Are you saying that every user must run a web server or a socket policy server on their PC and serve a policy file? The FTP server already has a socket policy server with a policy file accepting connections from any host to any port (<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" />).

Comment: No I'm saying that that the main server needs to serve and crossdomain.xml with the correct policies applied.Reference the link I provided.